# How do I solve an equation like this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

How do I solve following equation for $X$:

$$ AX^n + BX^{n-1} + CX^{n-2} + \dotsb + YX + Z = 0, $$

where $A,B,C,\dotsc,Z,n$ are known?

Comment: For $n=1,2,3,4$ there are general formulas. (Formulae?) For all other $n$, there is no general method for solving such an equation.

Comment: @Stefan there are methods for getting *approximate* solutions (as in, solutions to as many decimal places as you want).  Is that something you're interested in?

Comment: Which (numbers) are allowed for $X$ plays a part.  $X^2=5 $ has no solution if only natural numbers are only allowed.

Comment: Only real numbers are allowed, @Karl .

Comment: This is important $x^2=-1$ has no real solution for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ben S is correct. There are known formulae for $n=1,2,3,4$ and it's known to be impossible to find a general, exact solution beyond this.

However, this does not mean it can't be solved. Numerical methods can be used in general. See for example Newton Raphson methods and other similar things. You will only have at most $n$ real solutions.  If $n$ is odd you will have at least 1 real solution.

Another option (common for school problems) is to find one of the solutions by inspection. If $a$ is a solution then $(x-a)$ is a factor, so you can divide the original expression by $(x-a)$ and find another expression in $x^{n-1}$ to solve, which might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1,2,3,4$ there are general formulas. For all other $n$, there is no general method for solving such an equation.

Comment: But a computer can solve for n>4.How?

Comment: @Stefan Usually, computers just approximate the answers, unless the equation has some special form which allows it to be solved easily (like $x^n-1$ or something).

Answer (score 0):

I would add more: for $n\ge 5$, Galois theory proves there *cannot* exist any general formula, but that goes far beyond the level of precalculus.

For $n=5$, if the coefficients that satisfy special relations (more precisely if the Galois group of the equation has certain properties), there exist  a formula, or rather a program to calculate the roots, ands the code of this program (in Maple) is several pages long…

Comment: I met equaions with n=8 in 8th class of middle school...Certainly there is no acceptable way to solve it?

Comment: It must have had a special form. You also can find all the roots of $x^8-1$ in $\mathbf C$.But there can exist no *general* formula.